# Spring Autowire Return Null unless the window is loaded directly by the init method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I am very new to Spring, so I apologize in advance! If I load my fxml document directly from the init method, then everything works smoothly and Spring is able to access my database using my repositories which are autowired. However, the moment I change scenes, Spring can no longer locate the repositories/autowiring and it throws a null pointer exception for everything that involves Autowiring/my repositories. I believe I have all the proper annotations (@Repository for my repositories, @Controller for my controllers, @Entity for my models and so on) but nothing seems to help. In the example below, everything loads fine upon initial loading, but if I change windows or come back to this window, I just get a null pointer exception.

**Main Class/Spring Boot Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class Project3368Application extends Application {

@Autowired
private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
private Parent root;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    // Note that the root was already populated in the init function
    // root is of type Parent, and is a field in the class
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,800,400));
    System.out.println("showing page");
    primaryStage.show();
}

@Override
@Lazy // ?
public void init() throws Exception {
    springContext = SpringApplication.run(Project3368Application.class);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("newJobInfo.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    root = fxmlLoader.load();
    super.init();
}
```

}

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class NewJobInfoController implements Initializable {

public AnchorPane content;
@Autowired
MaterialRepository materialRepository;

@Autowired
ColorRepository colorRepository;

@Autowired
ShapeRepository shapeRepository;

public Button homeButton;

public ComboBox materialComboBox;
public ComboBox colorComboBox;
public ComboBox shapeComboBox;
public Label materialPriceLabel;
public Label colorPriceLabel;
public Label shapePriceLabel;
public Label totalLabel;


public void materialSelected(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    String materialPrice = " ";
   //System.out.println(materialComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());

   //Iterable<Material> materials = materialRepository.findByMaterial("Cotton");
   //materials.forEach(Material->System.out.println(Material.getPrice()));

    List<Material> materials = materialRepository.findByMaterial(materialComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());

   for (Material material : materials) {
        materialPrice = material.getPrice().toString();
    }


    materialPriceLabel.setText(materialPrice);

   double num1;
   double num2;
   double num3;
   double total;
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(materialPriceLabel.getText());
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(colorPriceLabel.getText());
    num3 = Double.parseDouble(shapePriceLabel.getText());
    total = num1 + num2 + num3;
   totalLabel.setText(Double.toString(total));

}

public void colorSelected(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    String colorPrice = " ";

    List<Color> colors = colorRepository.findByColor(colorComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());

    for (Color color : colors) {
        colorPrice = color.getPrice().toString();
    }


    colorPriceLabel.setText(colorPrice);
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double num3;
    double total;
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(materialPriceLabel.getText());
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(colorPriceLabel.getText());
    num3 = Double.parseDouble(shapePriceLabel.getText());
    total = num1 + num2 + num3;
    totalLabel.setText(Double.toString(total));
}

public void shapeSelected(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String shapePrice = " ";

    List<Shape> shapes = shapeRepository.findByShape(shapeComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());

    for (Shape shape : shapes) {
        shapePrice = shape.getPrice().toString();
    }


    shapePriceLabel.setText(shapePrice);
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double num3;
    double total;
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(materialPriceLabel.getText());
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(colorPriceLabel.getText());
    num3 = Double.parseDouble(shapePriceLabel.getText());
    total = num1 + num2 + num3;
    totalLabel.setText(Double.toString(total));
}



@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    materialComboBox.getItems().removeAll(materialComboBox.getItems());
    materialComboBox.getItems().addAll("Burlap", "Cotton", "Velvet", "Silk");
    materialComboBox.getSelectionModel().select("Burlap");

    colorComboBox.getItems().removeAll(colorComboBox.getItems());
    colorComboBox.getItems().addAll("White", "Red", "Green", "Gold");
    colorComboBox.getSelectionModel().select("White");

    shapeComboBox.getItems().removeAll(shapeComboBox.getItems());
    shapeComboBox.getItems().addAll("Sock", "Bone", "Candy Cane", "Paw Print");
    shapeComboBox.getSelectionModel().select("Sock");





}


public void homeButtonPushed(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    // Actually Change Screens
    Parent manageCustomerViewParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("kanban.fxml"));
    Scene manageCustomerViewScene = new Scene(manageCustomerViewParent);

    // This line gets the Stage Information
    Stage window = (Stage)((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    window.setScene(manageCustomerViewScene);
    window.show();
}

public void submitButtonPushed(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    // Actually Change Screens
    Parent manageCustomerViewParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("kanban.fxml"));
    Scene manageCustomerViewScene = new Scene(manageCustomerViewParent);

    // This line gets the Stage Information
    Stage window = (Stage)((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    window.setScene(manageCustomerViewScene);
    window.show();
}

@FXML
private void backButtonPushed(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
   Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("newJobPage1.fxml"));
   Scene parentScene = new Scene(parent);
   Stage window = (Stage)((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
   window.setScene(parentScene);
   window.show();
}
```

}

**Color Repository**

```
package project_3368.project_3368;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ColorRepository extends CrudRepository <Color, 
Integer> {
List<Color> findByColor(String color);
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.lambda$new$7(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:182)
at java.base/java.util.function.Consumer.lambda$andThen$0(Consumer.java:65)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.lambda$new$1(LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:86)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:106)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:151)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.updateValue(ComboBox.java:520)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.access$200(ComboBox.java:194)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$3.changed(ComboBox.java:503)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:105)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel.lambda$new$0(ComboBox.java:560)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:136)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:114)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:148)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:69)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:215)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.select(SingleSelectionModel.java:149)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.lambda$createListView$9(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:545)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:348)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:114)
at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:148)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:69)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:412)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:360)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1460)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:282)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:246)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:176)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at project_3368.project_3368.NewJobInfoController.colorSelected(NewJobInfoController.java:85)
    ... 102 more

Comment: Did you try debugging the `colorSelect` method line by line ? Also, this line `colorComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString()` doesnt seem healthy if you're not sure there'll be no NPEs thrown in any of those `get`s.

Comment: It works fine when I run it as the first window, and so does every other controller I have made... but not when it is a window I change scenes to.

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint in the very line where JVM throws exception at and performing a change scenes action ? Did you examine the local variables at that moment ? Because this line `java.lang.NullPointerException at project_3368.project_3368.NewJobInfoController.colorSelected(NewJobInfoController.java:85)` pointing at it.

Comment: I ended up changing how I switch scenes, and used a stage manager and changed the overall structure of the project. It ended up solving my problem

Comment: You should consider posting this as the temporary answer I think.